# Vue Server Worker how to call own function

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps

My Vue project has is a PWA.
In my project I have this `registerServiceWorker.js` script to control the update process like this

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import {register} from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
        ready() {
            console.log(
                'CRM has been loaded'
            )
        },
        registered() {
            console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
            setInterval(() => {
                self.update();
            }, 1000 * 60 * 60);
        },
        cached() {
            console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
        },
        updatefound() {
            console.log('New content is downloading.')
        },
        updated (registration) {
            console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
            document.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent('serviceWorkerUpdateEvent', { detail: registration })
            )
        },
        offline() {
            console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
        },
        error(error) {
            console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
        }
    })
}
```

My current problem is, that this is not working:

```js
        registered() {
            console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
            setInterval(() => {
                self.update();
            }, 1000 * 60 * 60);
        },
```

It says that `self.update is not a function`. How can I call the update function from the `registered()` function?

Comment: You do not have any `update` function in this scope. Neither its imported

Comment: ok that was a typo, but with the fix same thing `Uncaught TypeError: self.updated is not a function at registerServiceWorker.js:15`

Comment: You have no way of calling update on a service worker from your client side, you have to call .update() from your service worker file. The thing is with service workers is that you have to treat them like a separate thing in your projects, it is like a backend api of some sorts, you can not directly interact with it from your app, you can create a message which can trigger service worker update, if you so desire, but the only other way is to call skipWaiting and update from your service worker file.

Comment: But how can I call it from the `registered()` after some time?